# Add Left and Right Click Event to MenuItem

Tags: events, contextmenu, eventhandler

I`m trying to add a event for left and right click on a MenuItem.
Left click goes to an URL, right - call a context menu with option to delete this item from list.

However, addEventHandler as implemented has no effect.

```
FileUtils.getFileContentsAsArrayList(FileUtils.getBookMarksFile());
            for (int i = 0; i < FileUtils.getBookmarksContents().size(); i++) {
                String item = FileUtils.getBookmarksContents().get(i);
                MenuItem miNewItem = new MenuItem(item);
                    miNewItem.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)  
                                {System.out.println("LEFT");}
                                else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
                                {System.out.println("RIGTH");}

                            }
                    });
```

In a final code it should work as

```
            miNewItem.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)  
                            {MyJavaFXBrowser.getWebEngine().load(miNewItem.getText());}
                            else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
                            {removeBookmark().show(miNewItem, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());}

                        }
                });
```

But it gives an error -

```
The method show(Node, double, double) in the type ContextMenu is not applicable for the arguments (MenuItem, double, double)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by using CustomMenuItem insted of MenuItem.
and

```
CustomMenuItem cmi = new CustomMenuItem();
cmi.getContent().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()...
```